# ajax_deliver and Advanced Form Blocks issue

Tags: 7, ajax

I am new to AJAX framework in drupal 7.

**Scenario:**

I have two content types (Type-A and Type-B). I am displaying node add form of **Type-B** on **Type-A** edit form using [Advanced Form Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) module. 
There is another block which lists the nodes of Type-B. I want to refresh that block everytime Type-B node is created. I accomplished it by using the following code in [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) of my module:

```
    $commands = array();
    $html = views_embed_view('my-view', 'block_1', $nodeId);
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#wrapper', $html);

    $page =  array(
            '#type' => 'ajax',
            '#commands' => $commands,
    );   
    ajax_deliver($page);
```

which works fine but the Advanced Form Block (Type-B node add form) stopped showing the success message and the form is not getting reset which was happening before I implemented the code mentioned above. The nodes are getting saved just fine. I am assuming that somehow ajax_deliver is interrupting the default process that was happening before.

I would really appreciate some help regarding this.

Thanks in advance.